# snakemake with --conda-prefix, can I use a pre-built conda environment?

Tags: snakemake, conda

I have read this question ([Running Snakemake in one single conda env](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/6914/running-snakemake-in-one-single-conda-env)) but still have some doubt.

I am using the '--conda-prefix /some/dir' option and I have a rule in my snakemake file with the directive:

```
rule xxx:
  ...
  conda:    
    "envs/some.yaml"
  ...
```

The first call of that rule will create the conda environment according to the yaml file in /some/dir/envs with some random name (in my case 'bf55a79e'). If I run the workflow in a different directory, the same conda environment (/some/dir/envs/bf55a79e) gets activated directly instead of being built again. So this is what I expected.

My question is:

- is there some way of skipping the building and specifying that rule xxx should use an already existing conda environment somewhere?
- does anyone know where the mapping between rule and directory gets stored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If the environment already exists it will simply be used. You cannot, however, tell it to use an environment with a normal name (e.g., "my_env").
2. I assume you mean, "where the heck does the random looking conda environment name come from?!?", which is a very good question. The answer to that is that it's a hash of the `--conda-prefix` setting and the contents of the environment yaml file you specify. The actual code for doing this (I'm "stealing" it [from snakePipes](https://github.com/maxplanck-ie/snakepipes/blob/master/bin/snakePipes#L174)) is:

```py
import hashlib
md5hash = hashlib.md5()
md5hash.update("what you gave to --conda-prefix".encode())
f = open("your environment yaml file", 'rb')
md5hash.update(f.read())
f.close()
h = md5hash.hexdigest()
```

`h` is then the directory name. There are actually two lengths of those, the shorter 8 character version that snakeMake uses by default or the full length version that the code above will produce. snakeMake will actually use either of these. If you're wondering, no I don't think any of this is documented anywhere, you have to dig through the snakeMake code to find it.

Comment: Ok, that answers the core of my question! 
So if I change the way I refer to the conda-prefix (via symlinks or relative/absolute paths), the environment will get rebuilt. Which is perfectly acceptable as long as you understand what is happening.

Comment: Exactly, I'll suggest to Johannes that he document this somewhere :)

Comment: and just to be absolutely clear, if you don't specify a conda-prefix, the hash uses  the yaml file content only, right?

Comment: I actually don't know that off-hand, but I presume so. The conda environments end up under `.snakemake` in the output directory, so it's possible that it uses that path somewhere.

Comment: upon the first workflow run I had the `conda` directives in all rules, so that the virtual env was created (relative path to Snakefile is `../outSnakemake_ngs_bngs05b/.snakemake/conda/a87f68b4`). In order to suppress the creation of another (identical) environment I commented all the `conda` directives and called `snakemake -p -s Snakefile_v4_ngs_bngs05b --cluster "qsub -q researshq" -j 5 --use-conda --conda-prefix ../outSnakemake_ngs_bngs05b/.snakemake/conda/a87f68b4`, though the jobs failed. Is this the expected behaviour i.e. can I suppress the `conda` directives by specifying the env?

Comment: If the --conda-prefix doesn't change then an identical env won't be made (it'd have the same hash anyway).